# LiteDB "not in" query in powershell

Tags: powershell, litedb

I'm new to noSql databases, I can't figure out how to build a query like this

```sql
 "SELECT $ FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_FIELD NOT IN ("VALUE#1", ... "VALUE#N")"
```

in LiteDB

and another difficulty is that I may not know how many values will be in the section

that's all I could do by reading the documentation and browsing the internet:

```
using assembly .\lib\LiteDB.dll
[LiteDB.LiteDatabase]$db = [LiteDB.LiteDatabase]::new(".\lib\database.db")
$collection = $db.GetCollection("files", [LiteDB.BsonAutoId]::Int64)
$collection.Find([LiteDB.Query]::in("FILE_NAME","name1.ext", "name2.ext"))
$db.Dispose()
```